# React Router Link to same component with different URL not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component called Posts that lists all posts in a blog. I have links around the post's usernames which link to the same (Posts) component only with a different URL containing a user id to query the posts with. The problem is that the Posts component will not re-render upon visiting this URL, although the URL in the browser changes accordingly.

Routes in App.js:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Posts/>}/>
  <Route path='/user/:user_id/posts' element={<Posts/>}/>
</Routes>
```

Links in Posts.js

```
<Link to={`/user/${post.user.id}/posts`}>
  {post.user.username}
</Link>
```

I have tried various things including trying to add a key to the component but it didn't work. I also saw a "force re-render" code snippet but it was for a previous version of React Router.

How can I force the rendering of the Posts component in React Router v6?

Answer (score 1):

If `Posts` is rendered by a route that has changing route params

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Posts/>}/>
  <Route path='/user/:user_id/posts' element={<Posts/>}/>
</Routes>
```

then it should "listen" for changes to the route's match params.

In `Posts` use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams) hook to access the `user_id` route match param, and use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `user_id` to run/rerun any logic.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { user_id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (user_id) {
    // do something with user_id
  }
}, [user_id]);
```

If `Posts` is a class component, then either convert it to a function component so it can use React hooks, or create a wrapper component or a new [withRouter replacement](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) to use the hook and inject `params` as a prop.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but maybe this kind of code would work I think...?

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={props => <Posts {...props} />}/>
  <Route path='/user/:user_id/posts' element={props => <Posts {...props} />}/>
</Routes>
```

And if it does not works,
maybe just using `<a>` instead of `<Link>` might be work.

```
<a href={`/user/${post.user.id}/posts`}>
  {post.user.username}
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the above code a warning is triggered and the component is not rendered: "Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.". And using <a> instead of the <Link> triggers a full page refresh instead of using React Router.